# Detecting whether event title is work or leisure using sentiment analysis?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, sentiment-analysis, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am developing an event-booking application for individuals and want to differentiate between whether an event is a work event or leisure event simply by the title e.g. "Meeting at 5pm" would be work while "Concert" or "Lunch with John" would be leisure. I have heard about using sentiment analysis for detecting between stuff similar to this.

I am currently using DialogFlow ES for the NLP yet I can't seem to find anything to accomplish what I require. What tools are out there which I may be able to use for this task? I pretty much just need something that could be trained and differentiate between these two titles and would return some sort of number (e.g. between 0 and 1) so I can identify if it's more work or leisure.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a new entity which would capture if the appointment is for **work** or **leisure**. You can create an entity as described here. For instance, you can set the word `appointment` (with synonyms and similar words) in a `type` entity. Then, within the training phrases you make sure to select the entities if they are not detected automatically. Still under your intent, check the ***Required box*** and define a prompt to ask `Is this appointment for Work or Leisure?`. The bot will ask this information to the user and save it within the `type` intent, when not provided.

Comment: Continuing,  regarding the sentiment analysis, I don't think it would help you. Currently, it is available in DialogFlow, [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/sentiment), it gives an score and magnitude to the user's input, defining if it was neutral, positive or negative. Did it help you?